# URL can't be open due to DNS error

Tags: android, networking, mobile, dns, wifi

I've encountered an issue with opening local network URLs while connected to both WiFi and Mobile network. I mean, when I try to open an URL of a local server and the Mobile data transfer is on, the browser shows the DNS error. Should I turn the Mobile data transfer off so that only WiFi is working, the URL is opened.

Why is that? I always thought that the traffic would go through a WiFi connection first and then try to pass through the Mobile!